# How to find and return matched value from a column of strings in R?

Tags: r, substring

Suppose, column 1 contains directory(bunch of folders and stuff) of many files and the total directory is around 10,000. Columns 2 contains the folder name (there are 20 folders). I want to know which directories are from Column 2 folder names. I am trying to get a code that returns the matched folder name so that I will know which folder is being used and which are not. I was able to get TRUE or FALSE return but I can't get the match value.

If anyone can give me a direction how to do it, that would be great.

Comment: Please provide sample data using dput() and what you have tried so far (code)

Comment: str_detect(test$ap_database,"New_Folder")

All the folders starts with New_Folder. Such as, "New_Folder_1, New_Folder_2... and so on. My idea is to match 20 folder name with the rows of 10,000 and find which ones match and the name of the matched folder. I want to find which folder I have is not being used at all so that I can get rid of that folder. Like "New_Folder_8" is not used in column 1, then I am okay getting rid of that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try `grep(pattern, x, value = TRUE)`. It would be a good idea to provide a minimal reproducible example. I.e., we need a sample of the data you're working with.

Comment: On grep(pattern, x, value = TRUE), the pattern takes only 1 values. I have a list of value that needs to be matched. Supposed Row 5 matches with Folder_10, but Row 7 matches with Folder_3. I want to know which Folder is being matched with. If I don't see Folder_15 is not used in any of the rows, I will get rid of Folder_15.

Comment: Put it in a for loop and loop through each folder name that you wish to match.